Wide table breaks layout width
I have a table that is very wide. I have the overflow to auto. However, the table breaks the container and makes the page wider than the viewport by a small amount. It doesn't matter if I make the table width fixed smaller than the container width, it's still wider than the page. It also doesn't matter how wide I make the browser (3000px), it'll still have the same amount breaking out.
How can this be made so that the table is 100% of the container and does nto break the oage width.
The green box is the amount that is wider than the viewport.

